# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to integrate **Open Weather API** in my website, for this I have written some coding and it's working as expected in my local system. The same code is not working in Live. it's returning error and I have googled for this error and I tried so many examples like `xml` `json` `XMLHttpRequest` `jsonp` But all examples is working locally when Live it's not working. Throwing same error as below.

[image]

For above I have tried below code:

**Example 1**

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa&q=" + "Hyderabad";
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                weatherObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(weatherObj);
                if (weatherObj.cod && weatherObj.cod == 404) {
                    //$("#errLocationNotFound").hide().removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
                    //$("#output").parent().slideUp("fast", function () { this.classList.add("hidden") });
                }
                else {
                    //$("#errLocationNotFound").slideUp(function () { this.classList.add("hidden") });
                    //$("#output").html(getWeatherStr()).parent(".hidden").hide().removeClass("hidden").slideDown();;
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();

    });


</script>
```

**Example 2**

```
<script type="application/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Hyderabad,IN&mode=xml&appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data) {
                    /* handle data here */
                    console.log(data);

                    //$('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#weather_report');

                    /*var wrapper = $("#weather_report");
                     wrapper.empty();
                     wrapper.append("<div class='city'> <p>Place: " + data.city.name + "</p><p>Country: " + data.city.country + "</p></div>");
                     wrapper.append("<div class='day_1'> <p>Place: " + data.city.name + "</p><p>Country: " + data.city.country + "</p></div>");*/

                },
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    /* handle error here */
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

In **Example 2** I have tried both `xml`,`json` and `jsonp` **Mode** in **url** and **datatype**. But again throwing same Error.

Could you please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Its seems your domain is https and you sending request through http protocol your url should look like `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa&q=" + "Hyderabad"`

Comment: @aman_uni when I trying to access above url (with https) Browser throwing Error **Page cannot display**.

Comment: Are you using php seems your domain is not in php or not magento i think

Comment: @aman_uni Yes You are correct. I am trying to access `html` page with `JQuery` server is `IIS`.

Comment: If their is option to user `php` let me know will let you know alternate solution that may work for you and solve your problem

Comment: @aman_uni please post `php` alternate solution. I will enable `php` configurations from My Server. I think `IIS` will support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

That's because , you are using `HTTPS` protocol and calling api by `HTTP` protocol.

You have to convert Ajax requests to `HTTPS`

Otherwise try `CURL` with the answer/trick shown here by **@aman_uni**

Comment: how can i convert? help me on this?

Comment: simple : contact API provider

Comment: I have checked api endpoint not supporting https

Comment: `https` is paid, I think. check here : https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/8166727-http-to-https?t=535697

Comment: yes but if @magentotwo is using php and using magento framework will tell provide alternate solution.

Comment: @aman_uni : I'm not getting, what you want to say ???

Answer (score 0):

Here is your alternate answer :

Create a php file in your server called `weather.php` and write below mentioned code their.

```
<?php
$appid = $_GET['appid'];
$q = $_GET['q'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?appid=".$appid."&q=".$q);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
echo $output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

now you need to heat your ajax with url `https://www.yourdomain.com/weather.php?appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa&q=Hyderabad`

And you will receive json return from openweathermap.

Note: curl php extension must be enabled on your server.